# Mysql prepare execute returns false

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, php7

Tengo una tabla que se llama **alumnos** en una base de datos **phpmyadmin**, conectado mediante **PDO**,
todo va bien hasta que realizo la inserción a la tabla, donde en el ultimo paso `$sentencia->execute()` me devuelve false, impidiendo la inserción a la tabla. He mirado soluciones pero no consigo nada y no se porque se produce esto cuando mi **PDO** devuelve una conexión correcta.

**La tabla alumnos solo contiene en ese orden (id, nombre, contraseña, email)**

Realizando una inserción a una tabla con PDO :

```
function addUser($pdo){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO alumnos (id, nombre, contraseña, email) VALUES (NULL ,:nombre, :contraseña, :email)";
    $sentencia = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $sentencia->bindValue(":nombre",getUser()); 
    $sentencia->bindValue(":contraseña",getPassword());
    $sentencia->bindValue(":email",getEmail());
    var_dump($sentencia->execute());
    echo $pdo->lastInsertId();
}
```

Si alguien pudiera ayudarme por que se produce el error o una forma mejor de insertar con **PDO** lo agradecería.

Comment: Puede ser una tonteria, pero utilizar la ñ en el gestor de BBDD puede dar fallos a la hora de ejecutar consultas, intenta cambiar `contraseña` por `password` por ejemplo

Comment: No me lo puedo creer, era eso... muchísimas gracias @DevMind no sabes la de tiempo que me has ahorrado, para la próxima lo tendré en cuenta gracias.

Comment: Me alegra mucho que te haya servido. Saludos